# What to do about someone trying to cleanup questions from an old account?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was going through the suggested edit queue on StackOverflow and came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27759250) of someone trying to remove an image from a question.

The comment mentioned:

> This is my old account. I am cleaning up old questions.

In my opinion the image adds value to the question. It shows the coordinates inside the bins as a visualization of the data, which is relevant to the question.

Looking at the suggested edit history of the user, it shows that he has tried to remove this image already, which has been rejected:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25906569

So my question is. What should I do about someone trying to clean up their old account? Even if the edits don't seem to improve the question. My approach for now is to kind of ignore the comment and see judge myself if the edit improves the question.

Some more suggested edits of the user trying to cleanup his old account questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27759320
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27759322

Comment: The reason doesn't matter. If the edit improves the post, accept it, if it doesn't, reject.

Comment: @rene Alright, that seems logic enough, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the suggested edit removes important content from the post—as these seem to—then reject it as vandalism.

Consider also raising a moderator flag on one of the posts from the user who is suggesting the edits, alerting us to their campaign of vandalism. (No flag necessary in this case, of course, since a moderator has already seen it.)

Comment: Can you cover whether editing content of "my old account" considered "interaction between multiple accounts belonging to the same user" or not?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, it might, except that the "my old account" was nuked almost 2 years ago by a moderator (e.g., as a sockpuppet or a rule-evasion account). So suggesting an edit is really the only way for that content to be maintained.